# Ajax Calls in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is the best/easiest way to make a simple AJAX request to update a field in a view by requesting data from a controller?

Is it using an AJAX helper like @Ajax.ActionLink which uses jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js? I understand that this library isn't necessarily obsolete, but it worries me that it isn't included when you create a stock non-empty new MVC project.

I very much want to do things the MS way for this simple task (instead of doing it with jQuery directly) but it's hard to do with a lack of reference material or concrete examples using MVC 5/5.2.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

I am working with a project  using Asp.NET MVC 5.2, and haven't created a full-stack app in a while. The last time I worked with Asp.NET MVC, it was the first version.

There have been so many updates to the framework that it's hard to figure out what are the CURRENT best practices. Many examples of simple tasks like crud operations can be deprecated, and even new questions will reference older versions of MVC like 3 or 4.

Comment: Consider this: Doing it the jQuery way means you can transfer that knowledge to other frameworks/stacks.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the complexity of the actions you need to take after the call succeeds.(ie. is it a simple update field process or you need to do more actions or logic before displaying the data).

If it is a simple call i prefer using the ActionLink.

Here is a helful link about the ActionLink:
 http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/

But if you need to do more than just updating simple data fields you will need to do it using Jquery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/